# Browser based Code Editor, with real tabbing?

Tags: browser, editor, tabbing

I'm currently using CodeMirror as a browser based code editor, but what really annoys me is its lack of real tabbing. It uses spaces instead of tabs, and I just cant get my code as clean as desktop editor.

Are there any better editors out there?  It can be DOM based or Javascript or even browser specific, just as long as it gives me real tabs! :)

PS. I've had a look at Ace, which looks like it should do the job, but I cant seem to get real tabs to work - anyone tried it?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: Perhaps you've stumbled into the [ancient holy war](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-ev), and the editor writers aren't taking your side.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Jesus I never realised there was such a conflict. I couldn't imagine programming without tabs. Why use 3/4 spaces for indentation when you can use a single tab? Tabs are cleaner IMO.